# Silverlight 5 - OOB With Elevated Trust

Tags: c#, silverlight

To access local file system , I'm moving to Silverlight 5 from 4. I'm aware that we have now "In Browser" and "OOB" in Silverlight 5.

For "In Browser" local file system access, I came across certain mandatory deployment activities like signing a certificate, adding certificates to store and modifying registry to provide the elevated trust in order to access the local file system.

I would like to know, 
If I opt for **Out Of Browser mode with Elevated trust** in Silverlight 5, **do i still need to do the exact steps like signing certificate , modifying registry** etc or those are not required if it is a OOB application.

I'm completely aware of the security risks or potential harm of exposing data through OOB elevated app. However I'm interested only in whether OOB requires all that setups in deployment environment or it is only applicable for "In Browser" mode.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certificate signing or registry changes applies to - enabling trusted app(OOB) to run as in-browser (system admin now can do this starting SL5).Here is the reference [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg192793%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Coming to your question, OOB app doesn't require any such configuration because it is already having elevated trust as an app. it is applicable to in-browser elevated trust app explained in above article.

Comment: Hey Palak, Thanks for your response. I did went through the link. I was little confused as it says that the steps are required for IN BROWSER trusted application. Nowhere i could see that these are not required for OOB. That's why i raised this question here.

Comment: did you see **Note** on the half of the way in that article ? To power your in-browser app equally as OOB app, you should configure your in-browser app as OOB app irrespect whether client is going to install it as OOB. Now registry changes only required when you intentionally don't support in-browser app as OOB but still want your app should be having same power as OOB. If you enable OOB support, no settings required.

Comment: OOB apps are trusted apps. please see this [parent article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721083(v=vs.95).aspx "Trusted Applications").